# Difference between manifest and observed variables

Tags: python, factor-analysis, structural-equation-modeling

I try to code SEM model using the `semopy` package (https://arxiv.org/pdf/1905.09376v1.pdf), but there are 3 types of variables there - except latent, there are mainifest and observed variables. What's the difference?

I have some features in my data and planned to match them to some latent variables, but how the model should look like in this 3-variable system? Should my features be observed variables with one to one relation with some randomly created manifest variable, which will be matched with latents? What's the point of it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I agree that this is confusing.

Manifest variables and "observed" variables are both observed, in the sense that they are part of the input dataset, and not latent variables.

The distinction made in the `semopy` package is that manifest variables are part of the measurement model (ie the definition of the latent variables), whereas "observed" variables are part of the structural model (the relations between and among the latent variables and the "observed" variables)

From your description, you will define some latent variables as your measurement model, using the features as manifest variables. You won't have "observed" variables unless you have features that are part of the structural model.